# Creating a transparency mask for html

Tags: css, image, canvas, masking

Has anyone come across an effective way to mimic Webkit's

```
-webkit-mask-box-image: url(filename.png)
```

functionality?

I'm trying to use non-square animated elements, and would prefer not having to do the masking on server-side.

I'm set on supporting at least Gecko and Webkit, but if I can manage Opera and IE, that would be a bonus.

Comment: Answered a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887527/is-there-a-gecko-equivalent-to-webkit-mask-or-a-fancy-way-of-degrading-for-geck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Googling](http://www.google.no/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=mask+box+image&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) a lot, seems there is no way to do this with anything other than webkit at the moment. Just pre-mask your images in Photoshop for now :)

Comment: That was pretty much the conclusion I had come to - pre-masking in photoshop is not an option as it's a user-submitted image, which leaves masking in imagemagick or similar. Thankfully the shape I want to mask out is just simple geometry, so I've opted to use canvas and the clip() command.

Comment: Eh, that's a better idea then :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a div containing transparent images with higher z-index absolutely positioned over the top of the animations?

Just a thought, might be completely useless for what you need.

```
<div class="animation">
</div>
<div class="mas">
</div>

.animation{height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;}
.mask{height: 200px; width: 200px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 10; background: transparent url('mask.png') 0 0 no-repeat;}
```