# Is there a Gecko equivalent to -webkit-mask or a fancy way of degrading for Gecko browsers?

Tags: firefox, webkit, css, gecko

I'm looking for a solid answer on whether or not there is an equivalent to -webkit-mask in Gecko browsers/Firefox?

If not, is there any way of degrading -webkit-mask in CSS to a straight background-image deal or should I just give up and use Javascript?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Haven't seen a `-moz-mask` yet. I should totally make one for this year's Halloween.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're targeting firefox, it has great SVG support, so you can now use SVG masks instead of CSS. [Here is Mozillas documentation on how to do a mask in SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content) Webkit masks aren't standards track - so I have a personal doubt that you'll ever see them cross-browser.

Comment: Going to give this a shot. Also good to know that masks aren't standards track. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Just because I asked here. The answer is [yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-image#Syntax)

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with this for many hours, I was finally able to apply a complex SVG path as a mask for a div element on my site, and it works in Firefox. Here's what I did:

First, for Webkit browsers, the solution was ideal, and I simply had to make a flattened png file with the same size (or really the same shape, could be different scale) as the div I want to mask, and with the area I want to be visible in black, and the parts I want clipped out transparent. Then, I added the following line to the CSS for the div element I want to mask:

```
-webkit-mask-box-image: url(path/to/mask.png);
```

That was easy! Now let's get to the fun part of getting this working in Firefox. For this method to work, the vector shape must be the exact same size as the area you want to mask. So my mask is a relatively complex vector path designed in Fireworks, and I need to get it converted to an SVG path, and thankfully, I have Illustrator available. Otherwise, use your favorite SVG editor to convert your shape path to SVG. If you're also using Fireworks to draw your vector shapes, you can right-click on the vector shape you want to use, go to 'Edit' -> 'Copy Path Outlines', and then you can paste it into a sufficiently large document in Illustrator, or whatever SVG editor you're using.

Next, you need to export it to an SVG file. In Illustrator, I used the 'Export for Web' function, selected SVG format, version 1.0, and exported it to an SVG file. The position and document size don't really matter, as we're just after the path description, and we'll discard the rest.

So, now open that SVG file you just made with a text editor, such as Text Edit or Notepad. You'll see some XHTML-formatted content, and one element in particular is something like:

```
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0,43v0.5V44v0.5v1V46v0.5v1V48v0..."/>
```

The `d="..."` portion will probably be many lines long for a complex shape. This is the only portion of this SVG file that we care about.

Next, we must embed an SVG mask describing this path into our site HTML. First, let's add the following elements to our HTML:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <mask id="maskid" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
            <path fill="white" d=""/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Now, we simply copy the contents of the `d=""` property of the path element from the SVG file we saved earlier (i.e. M0,43v0...) and paste into the same `d=""` property of the path element in the embedded SVG's mask element. Then, we can add the following entry to the CSS for the element we want to mask:

```
mask: url("#maskid");
```

That's it. The path should now be applied as a mask to the element you specified.

Comment: This approach seems to have broken in FF 11, and was probably a bad idea from the start (embedding the XHTML SVG into the non-XHTML site HTML), so now I just moved the embedded SVG code above into a file with a .svg ending, and changed the CSS mask property value to: 'mask: url(path/to/maskfile.svg#maskid);'

Comment: Can you please provide a basic example on jsfiddle? I can't get this to work in Firefox :(

Comment: Couldn't get it to render correctly from js fiddle (maybe FF doesn't like cross-domain SVG links), but I got a demo running here: http://sandbox.lyra.fm/maskdemo

Comment: Thanks for this awesome example! And yes, FF doesn't allow cross-domain SVG links in CSS :( Setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't work. Do you know any other solution? (Except embedding it into the document.)

Comment: @TimPietrusky unfortunately, I don't know of any solutions to this besides hosting the SVG on the same domain as the HTML. It seems to be a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the trick , you need to convert all points generated in your svg file to ratio that is equal the point path divided by mask dimension .

For easier explaination , i have made a quick tool to help designers convert their svg into a mask that is compatible with firefox , you can see a live demo on my website ( http://www.prollygeek.com ) , for example the facebook logo , and twitter logo are just masks , and here is the tool that you can use to convert your svg to a mask:
http://prollygeek.com/svg-mask/

for example:

```
<mask id="fb"  maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<path d="M236.626,120.827v27.295h-14.851c-4.416,0-7.225,1.204-8.63,3.612c-1.003,1.604-1.405,4.415-1.405,8.229v12.442h25.287l-3.01,27.494H211.74v79.273h-32.712v-79.273h-16.055v-27.494h16.055v-16.457c0-16.858,5.82-27.695,17.259-32.311
c5.619-2.208,10.436-2.811,15.453-2.811H236.626z"/>
```

will be turned to:

```
<mask id="fb"  maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<path d="M0.59,0.3v0.0675h-0.035c-0.01,0-0.0175,0.0025-0.02,0.0075c-0.0025,0.0025-0.0025,0.01-0.0025,0.02v0.03h0.0625l-0.0075,0.0675H0.5275v0.1975h-0.08v-0.1975h-0.04v-0.0675h0.04v-0.04c0-0.04,0.0125-0.0675,0.0425-0.08c0.0125-0.005,0.025-0.005,0.0375-0.005H0.59z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#ffffff;"/>
```

Please dont forget to add this attribute style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#ffffff;"

and fill with any color , it doesnt matter.

afterwards link your mask to the css element you desire:

for example:

```
  mask:url(images/fb.svg#fb);
```

the calculator is free to use , but please dont copy or publish anywhere else.

Comment: It's a shame that the calculator ruins complex SVGs.

Comment: @DesignbyAdrian example ?

Comment: so what is the problem is works perfectly  !! only paste the vale inside (d) not the whole svg tag .http://jsfiddle.net/g7UbQ/2/

Comment: The red pig is broken and doesn't fit the width of the container.

Comment: because you have to use : maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" , also when using calculator make sure you type in the correct width of your svg , give me 10 minutes and i will send a working example .

Comment: save this image to your disk and run code on your pc , i just have a problem with linking svg internal mask to be used in FF http://jsfiddle.net/g7UbQ/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49868/discussion-between-design-by-adrian-and-prollygeek)

Comment: @ProllyGeek do you still have the calculator available?

Comment: @Matt yes indeed , but my site is down cause i was busy with other stuff , is there someway I can send it to you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply svg filters with css to HTML content in Gecko. [Here](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2008/06/applying_svg_ef.html) is an example from a guy who likes to fiddle with mozilla code. It is from 2008 so it might be a bit outdated.