# Mask Sizing on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to mask dynamically sized images on a webpage. The SVG mask I use for Chrome and Safari with their `webkit-mask-box-image` work great by resizing the mask to fit the element I'm using which in this case is an image. Is there any thing that is similar to `webkit-mask-box-image` for Gecko-baised browsers?

Comment: you can check my answer here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887527/is-there-a-gecko-equivalent-to-webkit-mask-or-a-fancy-way-of-degrading-for-geck/20164973#20164973

Comment: Thank's probably. I'll try that out. Also I found a library which I forked and added much on to if your interested: http://andreyonadam.github.io/imageMask/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen this html5rocks article? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Regardless, I think the best cross-browser solution for masks is `canvas`.